# How to downgrade mysql-client from 8.0.27 to 8.0.26 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-20.04, mysqldump

MySQL 8.0.27 has a bug when used to connect to Azure, where it uses all CPU resources and never connects.

Therefore I would like to downgrade to 8.0.26

What I have tried so far:

```
#uninstall any mysql references
get remove --purge -s 'mysql*'
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

#install mysql-client 8.0.26
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-client_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-client_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mysql-client
```

This throws the following exception:

```
mysql-client depends on mysql-community-client (>= 8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04); however:
Package mysql-community-client is not installed.
```

I assumed that Ubuntu would install the community-client dependency automatically, evidently it did not. How do I go about installing the appropriate dependencies for 8.0.26?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with the official Ubuntu packages and the even older version 8.0.19 works for you, you can simply downgrade by providing the version number.

```
sudo apt install mysql-client=8.0.19-0ubuntu5
```

You can list the available versions with `apt show mysql-client -a`, currently versions `8.0.19-0ubuntu5` and `8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1` are available for Ubuntu 20.04 from the official mirrors.

Afterwards you should run `apt-mark hold mysql-client` to prevent further updates of the package until you can verify that newer versions work for you.

Comment: Since this is an official ubuntu image, does that mean it is also still receiving security updates?

I know Ubuntu will continue to apply security updates for older versions of NGINX for example, but I am not familiar with their process for MySQL

Comment: Good question. TBH, I'm not sure, but [looking on the mirror](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/) the date of the package date is from 2020-04-05, so my guess would be "no". Funny thing is, the package for 8.0.26 is also still there, but not easily installable.

Comment: Do they make the package version that was just the most recent one a couple days ago immediately unavailable, and we gave to go all the way back to 8.0.19??

Answer (score 0):

In a brand new (clean) Ubuntu 20.04 container this is the command I ran. On your system you probably would need to remove some things to clean up y our old install. Not certain what. I also think installing this way is probably a bad idea, since it will not automatically update. When an updated version is available you need to remove these packages and manually install the new version, or go use the version available from the apt repo.

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:20.04

root@# apt update ; </dev/null apt install --yes --no-install-recommends wget ca-certificates &&
       mkdir mysql_8.0.26 ; cd mysql_8.0.26 && 
       wget -c \
            https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-client_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
            https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-client-core_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
            https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
            https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-common_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb &&
       </dev/null apt install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        ./mysql-community-client_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
        ./mysql-community-client-core_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
        ./mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb \
        ./mysql-common_8.0.26-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb

# ... lots of installing output.

root@# mysql --version

mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```